# How do I use getUserData() on my second scene, right after being loaded by my first scene?

Tags: java, javafx

My program has two scenes, `firstScene.fxml` and `secondScene.fxml`, each with corresponding Controller classes `FirstController.java` and `SecondController.java`.

I want to be able to use Stage's `getUserData()` on my SecondController class, after it has been loaded on the FirstController class using the **onAction** event of a Button, and an FXMLLoader.

This is a snippet of my code on the SecondController class:

```
    @FXML
    public void initialize() throws IOException {
        Stage window = (Stage) statusLabel.getScene().getWindow();
        statusLabel.setText("" + window.getUserData());
    }
```

`getUserData()` is based from my `setUserData(message)` on my FirstController class, where the value of `message` is a String.

This however outputs an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.Scene.getWindow()" because the return value of "javafx.scene.control.Label.getScene()" is null
```

How do I then use `getUserData()` on my SecondController class right after it has been loaded by my FirstController class?

Comment: When initialize is called the elements created by the fxml loader aren’t yet in a scene. That won’t happen until whatever loaded the fxml adds the resultant node from the loader into a scene. Then you could get the controller and call a method on it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml) and then do your work where you extract the user data you previously stored in the stage.  But that would all be weird and convoluted.  Mipa’s recommended approach or the mvc approach mentioned in the answer I linked is superior.

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for that info! Will read about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your GUI code should work with a common model. If you'd do that there is no need for controllers to talk with each other because they can all access the common model. Google vor MVVM to find some tutorial on this important aspect of any GUI programming.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Will read about MVVM.